# Binary search in Solidity arrays

Tags: solidity, contract-development, optimization

I have an array that will be subject to lookup and insertion operations. It is likely that it will increase in size considerably. Does solidity offer any means of performing efficient lookup operations? or libraries for binary search, for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, all the collection data types are very basic. This may be considered a design decision to keep the execution very cheap and will therefore not change in the future.
To my knowledge, no library for binary search in data types yet have been published. The only similar thing I know is the iterable map:
https://solidity-by-example.org/app/iterable-mapping/

Answer (score 4):

There's an implementation of binary search for sorted integer arrays, [here](https://gist.github.com/chriseth/0c671e0dac08c3630f47).

Note that this is look-up only, and you'll have to change the handled data type/structure from `int` to whatever your structure is.

Answer (score 4):

OpenZeppelin wrote a binary search algorithm in Solidity v0.8. Here's their implementation (code taken from [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.6.0/contracts/utils/Arrays.sol)):

```
function findUpperBound(uint256[] storage array, uint256 element) internal view returns (uint256) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    uint256 low = 0;
    uint256 high = array.length;

    while (low < high) {
        uint256 mid = Math.average(low, high);

        // Note that mid will always be strictly less than high (i.e. it will be a valid array index)
        // because Math.average rounds down (it does integer division with truncation).
        if (array[mid] > element) {
            high = mid;
        } else {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }

    // At this point `low` is the exclusive upper bound. We will return the inclusive upper bound.
    if (low > 0 && array[low - 1] == element) {
        return low - 1;
    } else {
        return low;
    }
}
```

And if you wonder what `Math.average` is, see [this](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.6.0/contracts/utils/math/Math.sol).

Comment: this is not a binary search, according to their documentation
 @dev Searches a sorted `array` and returns the first index that contains
     * a value greater or equal to `element`. If no such index exists (i.e. all
     * values in the array are strictly less than `element`), the array length is
     * returned. Time complexity O(log n).

Comment: I asked this question about binary search on Twitter and Frangio from OpenZeppelin [recommended](https://twitter.com/frangio_/status/1532739941926584321) the `findUpperBound` function.

Answer (score 2):

I've created an Order Statistics Tree that resolves a number of problems such as finding the median or rank of a value in a sorted list while also providing a method to cap gas cost to an absolute maximum/worst-case limit *at any scale*.

This repo builds on Bokky Poobah's Red Black Tree which provides the basis for the self-balancing tree. https://github.com/rob-Hitchens/OrderStatisticsTree